# How to add category dropdown in a popup when homepage load in Magent 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

First of all, I am very new to Magento.

I have seen resources to find my requirement, but it seems code folder in app folder is not there.
It is consuming my time a lot. Please help in doing this.

I want to add a Category Dropdown in a popup, when the homepage loads that popup should open, and based on selection of that category products should filter.

I need to know how to do, like what to do.. my requirement is that.. I mean I can write code. But where to write I don't know to achieve this

Comment: Hello @Swamy,

In Magento the app/code folder isn't there by default.

Comment: second thing add more description about your problem

Comment: I need to know how to do, like what to do.. my requirement is that.. I mean i can write code..but where to write i dont know to achieve this

Comment: If you worried about where to write your code ,
you need to create code folder manually inside app and create your custom modules there for your requirements

Comment: please can you give more detailed